# How to write an if statement for a specific error message in an exception?

Tags: python

I am trying to raise an exception only when a specific error message occurs. In my example I need the string `stl_load_error` to be present in the error message.

```
try:
    generic s3 copy command

except Exception as exec:
    if 'stl_load_error' in exec:
```

When I evaluate `exec`, `exec` = `{InternalError}Load into table some_table failed. Check stl_load_errors system table for details. \n`

However, my code is breaking at the if statement. Is there a correct way to do this?

Comment: try chaning it to `if 'stl_load_error' in str(exec):`... although you should really be checking for the exception type, not its message.

Comment: If you have control over the code that raises the exception, it would probably be more correct to create a new exception type for just this scenario.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try converting the exception to a string before doing a string operation on it:

```
try:
    generic s3 copy command
except InternalError as err:
    if 'stl_load_error' in str(err):
```

(also, it's better to catch the specific exception class rather than `Exception`!)